# Gracefully kill a call to a method which is taking too long

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, kill-process

I have a background worker with the task of downloading large numbers of small files and saving them on the hard disk. To give you an idea of scale, 30 million files.

The background worker is cancellable and I can cancel just fine once I begin downloading the files. But I can't cancel during the call to the external dll method which tells me what files to download. I have an external dll with a method I call which returns this long list of files. It can take hours to complete just that one single method.

I really need to be able to cancel this call. For example, the user gets frustrated with the time it's taking and hits cancel. Right now, I have the wait until that method completes before I can cancel.

Here is an example:

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    TimeIntensiveMethod(); // Can take up to an hour - can't cancel it

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
            break;

        ShortDurationMethod(); // The wait to complete before cancelling is unperceivable
    }
}
```

In this example, I want to be able to cancel on the `TimeIntensiveMethod` while it's in the middle of working. Is this possible?

Comment: A very good example of how to wrap this in a Task and kill the task: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @DavidHaney: If I understand correctly, the monolithic call to `TimeIntensiveMethod` prevents this from being a good approach, unless it can be rewritten to support cancellation.

Comment: @spender you might be right. We know nothing about the `TimeIntensiveMethod` unfortunately.

Comment: The `TimeIntensiveMethod` is native code from an external dll and I don't have access to the source. I'm stuck using this method. It is computational only in nature and does not effect the UI or conduct any I/O operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only more or less reliable way to cancel the execution of native code, is to run it in a separate process, and to stop that process.

That will work reliably only if that process doesn't do I/O though. If it does, who knows what happens if it is interrupted in the middle of an I/O operation.

There are several ways to run the call in a separate process, and to marshal the parameters and return values across the process boundary. Using WCF is one option. Using the [managed add-in framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145020.aspx) is another one (though I would not recommend it). Running a console program using the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class and capturing the output stream is probably the best option.

Answer (score -1):

As a simple and care-free alternative to out-of-process call, you can simply start a new thread, make the call in it, and terminate that thread from your main thread if you feel like it.

You'll have some resource-leakage, but if it is an user-driven app, it might be acceptable...

EDIT:

One other method would be to BREAK the process intentionally from behind, for example if it is file enumeration, lock some files to make enumeration fail and exit...

Comment: Terminating a thread should only be done cooperatively. `Thread.Abort` is extremely unsafe.

Comment: Thread.Abort() will have no effect if the code in the DLL is native code. And as @usr pointed out, even with managed code, it is unreliable.

Comment: It is.  As I pointed out: care-free.  If you can get away with it, do it.

Comment: From the MSDN documentation: "The thread is not guaranteed to abort immediately, or at all." See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx